# Couldn't locate driver named sqlite

Tags: sqlite, symfony1, doctrine

symfony 1.2, doctrine, dsn: sqlite:%sf_data_dir%/db.sq3

When i am trying "php symfony dctrine:build-sql" i get this error, but on frontend all fine.
Also i have tried to change ini file this way

```
php -c "path to file" symfony doctrine:build-sql
```

but get the same error

Couldn't locate driver named sqlite

Comment: Perhaps your apache uses a different php.ini than cli, resulting in the sqlite pdo extension not being loaded.

Comment: i have tried another ini file that uses in frontend but get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Added to symfony script file `dl(pdo_sqlite.so);`
It works!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the php5-sqlite package in Ubuntu.